# Какие TagId у тегов в SQL-бд ruSO?

Tags: sql

Увидел вопрос "[Новогодний Алгоритм 2019](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8460/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-2019?cb=1)". Там для получения результатов конкурса используются sql запросы. Так как я сейчас учу sql и базы данных, мне стало интересно разобраться с этим подробнее и поюзать sql запросы. 
В sql запросе есть таблица `PostTag`, у этой таблицы есть колонка `TagId`. Я хочу узнать, какому тегу соответствует какой `Id`. Например, тегу `алгоритм` соответсвует `Id` 38. Как это сделать? Может с помощью какого-то sql запроса?

После `SELECT * FROM PostTag` выходит таблица с 2-мя колонками: `PostId` `TagId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить все теги:

```
SELECT * FROM tags
```

Пример: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/955201

Конкретно для тега:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE TagName = 'sql'
```

Пример:
https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/955200

То есть вы можете сделать `join` к таблице `tags` и получить его `id`.